# ionic ion-slide-box collapsing after a change in ng-repeat

Tags: ionic-framework

```
<ion-slide-box does-continue="true" auto-play="true" slide-interval="1000">
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="imageUrl in item.images">
    <img src="{{imageUrl}}"><img/>
    </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
```

My code above collapses after i change "item" in my controller with help of a button.

Whenever the button is clicked,I tried to do the followings with following order ;

```
1) $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.stop(); 
2) Change $scope.item = newITEM;
3) $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
4) $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.start();
```

But apparently, it doesn't work like this. What would be the solution to solve?

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Similar as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31402430/ion-slide-box-update-issue/31406766), try to use `$timeout` after you do the update, like this:

```
1) $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.stop();
2) Change $scope.item = newITEM;
3) $timeout(function(){
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.start();
     }, 500);
```

Comment: Turns out this solution doesn't work for autoplay as it can be experienced from here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNjpoW  . update() function doesn't remove it's previous content..