# ion-slide-box Update Issue

Tags: ionic-framework

```
<ion-slide-box>
     <ion-slide ng-repeat="imageUrl in item.images">
              <img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" />
      </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

and my Controller:

```
$scope.changeItem = function(differentItem) {
        $scope.item = differentItem;
        //$scope.$apply();
        $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
    };
```

Whenever the changeItem() button is clicked, it changes $scope.item which i use in ng-repeat(in slide-box).

My problem here is that `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();` doesn't update and set the pager index to 0 with the new number of images of the selected item even though the $scope.item changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**edit:** Indeed, this seems like a known issue, as noted on the [official Ionic forum](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/slides-generated-with-ng-repeat-causing-issues-slide-box/394/23). However, I made the example work as you can see [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVEjJV). Things I've changed are the following:

- I updated the ionic to version 1.0.1 (you can see the links from http://code.ionicframework.com/)
- used the `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(0);` because it otherwise fails again if you click the button when on the last image
- used the `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update()` as you were trying, but inside the `$timeout` since (as you will read on forum) it could be that the items are not yet rendered when you call the `update()` method on `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate`;

Updated code, here for reference:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http, $ionicSlideBoxDelegate, $timeout) {
  $scope.item = {};

 $scope.item.images = [
  'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/',
  'http://lorempixel.com/400/300/',
  'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/',
 ];


 $scope.changeImages = function(){
  $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(0);
    
    $scope.item.images = [
   'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/',
   'http://lorempixel.com/300/300/'
  ];
    
    $timeout(function(){
     $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update(); 
    }, 500);
      
 };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    
    <title>Ionic Template</title>

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <ion-slide-box show-pager="true">
     <ion-slide ng-repeat="imageUrl in item.images track by $index">
              <img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" />
              <button class="button" ng-click="changeImages()">change imgs</button>
      </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

**--edit end--**

I made a test project on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVEjJV), and as you can see, changing the `images` on the `item` object updates accordingly.

So, without seeing the rest of your code, we can't help. You can make a similar CodePen example with your code, so that we can see immediately what may be wrong with it.

Code pasted here for reference:

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.item = {};

 $scope.item.images = [
  'http://lorempixel.com/400/200/',
  'http://lorempixel.com/400/300/',
  'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/',
 ];


 $scope.changeImages = function(){
  $scope.item.images = [
   'http://lorempixel.com/200/200/',
   'http://lorempixel.com/300/300/',
   'http://lorempixel.com/500/400/',
  ];  
 };
});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    
    <title>Ionic Template</title>

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.25/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/0.9.25/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    
    <ion-header-bar title="myTitle"></ion-header-bar>

    <ion-pane class="has-header" padding="true">
      <h2>You can't see me</h2>
    </ion-pane>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello @Nikola, Codepen you've made shows the exact error that i'm getting. Please try to remove one item from the array in chageImage() function. So initially, there are 3 images, after changeImages() function is called, there should be  2images. And then run the code, try to go to the last image of the initial array(with three images), then press changeImages button, you will see that the pager is not refreshed pointing on the 3.image. But our array has changed and theres no 3.image anymore. My error is exactly this issue. The Error appears clear when two different array sizes are used.

Comment: @SerhanOztekin: Actually, this turned out to be a great question, since it took me quite a while to figure out the problem. I upvoted your question because of that. And, in the updated answer you'll see the solution. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for saving my life! after updating to 1.0.1 and following your instructions, the problem is solved. However, $timeout function delays rendering images and causes to observe the transition between the items. We are able to see the stack or previous, next items while the transition takes place. I tried to set the timeout lower than you've set which was 500, but then the pager doesn't work accurate(doesn't remove the last dot). Any ideas on that? In the end, if there's no solution for it, i will remove the pager and $timeout which i can obtain a clear transition.

Comment: @SerhanOztekin: no problem - glad to help, as this, as it seems, was quite an issue, judging from the forum comments. Anyways, make sure you accept the answer. Good luck with further Ionicization ;)

Comment: just edited my comment above, please have a look at it, Thank you. @Nikola

Comment: As far as I know, and as far as I've seen on the forum there seems to not be a solution to this (at least not yet). Yes, I was also trying with smaller timeout versions, but it seems they don't work to well, as you noted. So, for now this should be considered as a "hack", but since it's the only thing that works I'm afraid we'll have to use it as such.